# LibUSBJava write failed

Tags: java, camera, usb, libusb

I want to write data to a USB camera on Java. For doing that, I'm using [LibUSBJava](http://libusbjava.sourceforge.net/wp/). I can open USB camera and read data successfully, but when I try to write data, I can not find any `output endpoint` on the opened device. For finding `output endpoint`, I have implemented this function. When I call this function, it returns `null`. I debugged this method and figured out `dev` has 4 interfaces. All of them have `input endpoint`, but there is no `output endpoint` on these interfaces.

```java
private static Integer getActiveOutputEndPoint(Device dev) {
    try {
        Configuration cd = dev.getConfiguration();
        if (cd == null)
            System.out.println("Configuration Descriptor: null!");
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < cd.getNumInterfaces(); i++) {
                Interface ifc = cd.getInterface(i, 0);
                if (ifc == null)
                    System.out.println("Interface Descriptor: null!");
                else {
                    for (int k = 0; k < ifc.getNumEndpoints(); k++) {

                        Endpoint ep = ifc.getEndpoint(k);
                        if (ep == null)
                            System.out.println("Endpoint Descriptor: null!");
                        else {
                            if (ep.isInput()) {
                                continue;
                            } else {
                                return ep.getEndpointAddress(); 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR ! Configuration Descriptor: null! or Interface Descriptor: null!");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is there anybody who can help me?

Comment: @DuncanJones: this method returns null.

Comment: Are you sure what you camera allows writing data? If there is no output interfaces in it I think it's much probability.

Comment: @Nestor: So how I can send PTP command to camera?